# Excel Macro & VBA, Copy Cell Range to another sheet (transposed and based on another value)

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to frankenstein a solution from different threads but I am very much a newbie to VBA and programming, so it has not been going too well...

Here's some basic info:

- I have 2 Sheets within the same workbook (Database and Data entry)
- They contain the same headers, but are transposed (Database has the headers in the columns while Data entry has them in the rows)

Now, I am looking for 3 things (ideally in one compact solution)

1. Have a Command Button that copies and transposes the most recent range (leftmost column) from Data Entry to Database. (This is done in the code below)
2. This should be done depending on a certain cell value on the data entry sheet (ideally that cell could stay part of the copied range, however this is not crucial)
3. Delete  the original range from the data entry sheet.

As I said I'm just starting to work with VBA so I am completely unsure how to go about this, I have attached what I gathered so far (excludes Nr.2 and feels very cumbersome overall). Any help is very much appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Set xSheet = ActiveSheet
        If xSheet.Name <> "Definitions" And xSheet.Name <> "fx" And xSheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
            xSheet.Range("E6:E200").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:AZ6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code produce errors?

Comment: @BradDixon no it does not

Comment: Number 2 is too broad. What kind of value? Where? Should it be done automatically when user provides certain value? What if the value is not correct for coping values?
For number 3 you can just use `Cut` instead of `Copy` or delete the entire column.

Comment: I can’t see any “certain” cell value check in your code

Comment: @EganWolf Sorry for being unable to express it more clearly, so regarding no. 2, the cell is currently within the range of cells to be copied and it's either left blank or "Y". It doesn't have to be automatic at the time of filling in the cell just when the commandbutton is pressed. Thanks for your suggestion regarding  `cut` and `delete` however for me only the latter seemed to work. Replacing `copy` with `cut` gave me a run-time error 1004 (PasteSpecial method of Range class failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one. It checks the value of E10. If it's "Y", then data is copied and deleted from original place. Otherwise, it shows a message to the user.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Set xSheet = ActiveSheet
        If xSheet.Name <> "Definitions" And xSheet.Name <> "fx" And xSheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
            If xSheet.Range("E10")="Y"
                xSheet.Range("E6:E200").Copy
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:AZ6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                xSheet.Columns("E").Delete
            Else
                MsgBox("Data entry not ready!")
            End If
        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```